# Deserializing UITest using XMLSearializer, few Action collections are blank, while Maps are fine

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer, coded-ui-tests

I am trying to programatically edit the uitest file generated by Visual Studio 2012. 
I am deserializing a uitest file (which I am guessing just serialized XML for [UITest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.UITest%29;k%28UITest%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) class) using a standard XmlSerializer methods. The below code works just fine for the UIMaps, but it does not load any Actions. `InitializeActions`, `ExecuteActions`, `CleanupAction`s and `OnErrorActions` are all blank, while UIMaps section loads.

What am I missing?

Note: To run this piece of code add reference to:

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Common.dll, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll.
```

And here is the code I am using:

```
var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(UITest), new XmlRootAttribute() { ElementName = "UITest", Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/TeamTest/UITest/2010" });
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
{
    try
    {
        UITest uiTest = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream) as UITest;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Fail(e.Message, e.InnerException.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `UITest uiTest = UITest.Create(uitestFilePath);` instead.